How can I prevent overflow in the diagram?
Overflow happens at the left side. How can I solve it?
here is the code . May I know where overflow occur?
why the overflow only occur at the left side sizedbox?
I tried to reduce the size of sizedbox allocated for the gauge but overflow occur also
I also tried to increase the size of the sizedbox allocated for the gauge, also it does not work
enter image description here
                //This is the class to set value for the gauge
                class Gauge extends StatelessWidget {
                  final String title;
                  final double value;
                  final double rangeValue;

                  const Gauge({
                    Key? key,
                    required this.title,
                    required this.value,
                    required this.rangeValue,
                  }) : super(key: key);

                  @override
                  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      width: 160,
                      height: 160,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 150,
                              height: 150,
                              child: SfRadialGauge(
                                title: GaugeTitle(
                                  text: title,
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                axes: <RadialAxis>[
                                  RadialAxis(
                                    axisLineStyle: const AxisLineStyle(thickness: 15),
                                    startAngle: 180,
                                    endAngle: 360,
                                    interval: 50,
                                    minimum: 0,
                                    maximum: 100,
                                    canScaleToFit: true,
                                    showLabels: false,
                                    pointers: <GaugePointer>[
                                      MarkerPointer(
                                        enableAnimation: true,
                                        value: value,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        markerOffset: -10,
                                      ),
                                      RangePointer(
                                        value: rangeValue,
                                        width: 15,
                                        enableAnimation: true,
                                        color: value <= 25 || value >= 80
                                            ? Colors.red
                                            : Colors.green,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }

                //This is the class that provide the interface in the diagram
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, left: 29.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                                  width: 150,
                                  height: 150,
                                  child: const Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Gauge(
                                            title: 'Steam Pressure',
                                            value: 60,
                                            rangeValue: 60,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                                          Gauge(
                                            title: 'Steam Flow',
                                            value: 22.82,
                                            rangeValue: 22.82,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Gauge(
                                            title: 'Water Level',
                                            value: 55.41,
                                            rangeValue: 55.41,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                                          Gauge(
                                            title: 'Power Frequency',
                                            value: 50.08,
                                            rangeValue: 50.08,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),


Try it to wrap with Expanded widget.

When using fixed Size for your widget. so all depends on you.
Your gauge chart is 160 *160 px.
How can you put a column that contains many gauge charts within a container whose height is 160 *160 also.
All these gauges require at least a dimensions = 320 *320 (frequency, level, pressure....).
So, Remove that container:
  child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
         // width: 150,
         // height: 150,
          child: const Column(

You can either remove the container or don't specify a dimensions for it.
